# How to get perticular (highway) road's number of lanes?

Tags: postman, here-api

I am using https://developer.here.com/develop/rest-apis to get the perticular (highway) road's number of lanes

e.g. If person/vehicle want to reach from (waypoint0)- (Place X) to (waypoint1)- (Place Y) then on that way how many lanes available ?

like Highway #1 has two lanes or four lanes available.

Currently I am passing below **Rest API** but i could not see any Lane details :

1. https://route.api.here.com/routing/7.2/calculateroute.json?app_id=XXXXXX&app_code=XXXXXXXX&waypoint0=geo!23.036611,72.561203&waypoint1=geo!23.034449,72.560581&mode=fastest;car;traffic:disabled

2.https://transit.api.here.com/v3/route.json?app_id=XXXXXX&app_code=XXXXX&routing=all&dep=23.036637,72.561189&arr=23.038600,72.564685&time=2018-08-23T07%3A30%3A00

2. https://wse.api.here.com/2/findsequence.json?start=swastik;23.036611,72.561203&destination1=C G Road;23.034449,72.560581&mode=fastest;car&app_id=XXXXXXX&app_code=YYYYYY

Also please suggest me any other API to get number of lanes of particular road.

Answer (score 1):

Did you had a look at the Platform Data Extension API? There is an example here (tcs.ext.here.com/examples/v3/pde_get_any_link_info) which illustrates this approach.

Further documentation can be found here:
https://developer.here.com/documentation/platform-data/topics/what-is.html