# is there a way to know how many lanes in a road?

Tags: google-maps, azure-maps

Currently, I'm working on a Mapping Project , and I'd like to know if there's a way to know how many lanes in a single road (same direction), using one of Maps API, like google map. Because at the end I have to display if a lane is blocked, which kind of vehicles can go on a lane, and also the speed limit. But for now I just need to display the number of lanes.

For my application, I'm using Xamarin and Xamarin.forms.maps to display the map and also the Plugin.geolocator for some geolocation informations.

Comment: No, there is no way. It's theoretically possible using Here Rest APIs (see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51963026/how-to-get-perticular-highway-roads-number-of-lanes), but personally I haven't tried that.

Answer (score 1):

This feature has been requested in the Issue Tracker of Google Maps APIs. However, the request has been rejected as it will violate the compliance of the Google Maps Platform Terms of Service.

They said in the request:

> Unfortunately, exposing this in the Directions API would encourage use
>   of the Maps APIs in ways that would not be in compliance with the
>   Google Maps/Google Earth APIs Terms of Service at
>   https://developers.google.com/maps/terms#10-license-restrictions
>
> 10.4 Restrictions on Unfair Exploitation of the Service and Content.
>
> c. Restrictions on your Maps API Implementations.
>
> iii: No navigation. You will not use the Service or Content for or in
>   connection with (a) real-time navigation or route guidance; or (b)
>   automatic or autonomous vehicle control.

You may check the Feature Request [here](https://issuetracker.google.com/35828052).

This is only applicable to Google Maps Platform, I'm not sure though with other Maps provider. Hope this helps.